# How to select multiple slides in PowerPoint and then Duplicate them multiple times?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to duplicate selected slides multiple times in the same presentation. Could someone please advise where I am going wrong? Thank you

```
Public Sub DuplicateSlideMultipleTimes()
    Dim n As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    n = InputBox("How many copies of the selected slides do you want to make?")

    Dim mySlides As Slides
    Set mySlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

    If n >= 1 Then
        For numtimes = 1 To n
            mySlides.Copy After:=ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach.  Instead of looping through each of the selected slides to make a duplicate, it simply copies and pastes.  It also places them at the end of the presentation.

Note that `mySlides` has been appropriately declared as a SlideRange, as Ricardo has already pointed out.

Also note that `On Error Resume Next` has been removed, since it can hide errors when not used properly, as Ricardo has also pointed out.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DuplicateSlideMultipleTimes()

    Dim ans As String
    Dim num_copies As Long

    num_copies = 0
    Do
        ans = InputBox("How many copies of the selected slides do you want to make?")
        If Len(ans) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If IsNumeric(ans) Then
            num_copies = CLng(ans)
            If num_copies > 1 Then Exit Do
        End If
        MsgBox "Invalid entry, try again!", vbExclamation
    Loop

    Dim mySlides As SlideRange
    Set mySlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To num_copies
        mySlides.Copy
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste
    Next i

    MsgBox "Completed!", vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close.

### Some highlights:

1. Avoid On Error Resume Next whenever possible (this will just hide where you have errors)
2. Declare all your variables (use Option Explicit at the top of your modules)
3. You have some variables types wrong

Review code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DuplicateSlideMultipleTimes()

    Dim sourceSlide As Slide
    Dim selectedSlides As SlideRange

    Dim numTimes As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim totalCounter As Long

    ' Ask user for num slides
    numTimes = InputBox("How many copies of the selected slides do you want to make?")

    ' Check if numTimes is a number otherwise, exit procedure
    If Not IsNumeric(numTimes) Then Exit Sub

    ' Set a reference to the selected slides
    Set selectedSlides = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

    ' Loop through each slide in the selected slides
    For Each sourceSlide In selectedSlides
        For counter = 1 To numTimes
            ' Duplicate the slide
            sourceSlide.Duplicate
            ' Track total number of duplicated slides
            totalCounter = totalCounter + 1
        Next counter
    Next sourceSlide

    ' Display message to user
    MsgBox totalCounter & " duplicates generated"

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works